# Shell (Bash) - Can I have fully portable .bash_profile / .bashrc / .bash_history files?

Tags: shell, git-bash, bash, portable-applications

**Background**

I'm a Front End Web Developer that has started moving to PortableApps where I can; at least for the desktop machines I use (Windows) after building a machine and having to re-install Windows multiple times.

It's getting more and more important to use the command line with build automation tools, testing software with a CLI etc.

I have just got portable versions of Git (Bash) and ConEmu working from my Dropbox (but ideally this would work from USB too). This means I have access to a Unix shell on Windows with Git, but the .bash_profile (and .bashrc) I have saved I need to manually copy to the '~' (home) directory for each machine I use.

**Question**

Is there a way to link my portable console with bash files **not** located in the home directory of the user on each machine used?

For instance when my console opens and looks for these files, can I ask it to check a different directory without setting any config on each machine? And then get the .bash_history to save here too instead?

Comment: dont know it works on windows, but on linux & mac you can use git: https://dotfiles.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use symbolic links for `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`:

```
ln -s /path/to/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
ln -s /path/to/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
```

And inside your `.bashrc` you can define where your [history file is located](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html):

```
export HISTFILE=/path/to/.bash_history
```

I don't think there's any way around having `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` in your home directory. Unless you start bash with the `--rcfile` option:

```
bash --rcfile /path/to/.bashrc
```

There is also the system wide file located at `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response but I have tried this and it seems that when I create the symbolic link, the contents are accurate. When I then change the source file (tried originally on different HDD then the same) when opening '~/.bash_profile' it still shows the original contents?

Comment: The above comment applies to Windows, it does not apply to Mac, and I now have this working perfectly on a Mac. Thanks! Just hope I can get Windows working the same way!